# How to set virtual enviroment manually using pipenv?

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code, pipenv, python-3.8

After I type pipenv shell in command line for create a new virtual enviroment it show off this message: Failed to create virtual environment. Sorry, but I don't saw nothing about this here.

I tried to install some extensions and packages but unsucessfully. I also verified the path of enviroment variables ans it are corretly.

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\dev\Python\app\Pipfile
Using c:\users\Jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe (3.8.0) to create virtualenv…
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter c:\users\Jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\Jason\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\Jason\.virtualenvs\app-fmoswTX-\Scripts\python.exe
Command C:\Users\Jason\.virt...-\Scripts\python.exe -m pip config list had error code 1
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

  Complete output from command C:\Users\Jason\.virt...-\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 385, in shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       do_shell(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2155, in do_shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_project(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 570, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 505, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       do_create_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 934, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       raise exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2628, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 860, in main
    create_environment(
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1173, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1019, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1110, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir 
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "c:\users\jason\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 963, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\Users\Jason\.virt...-\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I hope to create this project using pipenv.

Comment: This has already been reported as a bug to `pipenv`: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3996

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc